# updated json data not showing in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

retrieve json data from my server. first time showing the data in my app. but while updating new data, it's not showing. only showing the old data.. while i'm clearing cache from the app, then it's showing the updated data. but i want to show real-time data in same time. what i have to do? please help me.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext ;
    private List<Anime> mData ;
    RequestOptions option;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

        // Request option for Glide
        option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anime_row_item,parent,false) ;
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view) ;
        viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Read.class);
                i.putExtra("news_title",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                i.putExtra("news_description",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDescription());
                i.putExtra("anime_studio",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAuthor());
                i.putExtra("anime_category",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getCategorie());
                i.putExtra("anime_img",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImage_url());

                mContext.startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.post_title.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.date.setText(mData.get(position).getDate());
        holder.author.setText(mData.get(position).getAuthor());
        holder.cat_name.setText(mData.get(position).getCategorie());

        // Load Image from the internet and set it into Imageview using Glide
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImage_url()).apply(option).into(holder.thumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView post_title ;
        TextView date ;
        TextView author ;
        TextView cat_name;
        ImageView thumbnail;
        LinearLayout view_container;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            post_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            cat_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        }
    }
}
```

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    private final String JSON_URL = "https://mywebsite.org/news/api.php";
    private JsonArrayRequest request ;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
    private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    ProgressBar loading;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        loading = (ProgressBar)root.findViewById(R.id.bar);
        loading.setMax(100);
        lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);

        jsonrequest();

        return root;
    }

    private void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {

                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                        Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                        anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        anime.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                        anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("category"));
                        anime.setAuthor(jsonObject.getString("admin"));
                        anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail"));
                        lstAnime.add(anime);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    //This indicates that the request has either time out or there is no connection
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TimeOut...! No Internet",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    // Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed To Receive Data",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    //Indicates that the server responded with a error response
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Our Server Under Maintenance",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //Indicates that there was network error while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Not Responding",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    // Indicates that the server response could not be parsed
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Reload Again!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {

        RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),lstAnime);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

        // grid columns is 2
        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                // 0 is first one and 9 is first one all of others are 2 columns
                if (position == 0 || position == 9) {
                    return 2;
                }
                return 1;}
        });
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);

    }

}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".fragments.Home"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/bar"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerviewid">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your recycler view not showing the updated data?

Comment: How you "update data"? I see the Request to server is made only once in "onCreateView()", so only when the Fragment is created the request is made. So if you update server's data you have to re-execute the request....

Comment: @emandt can you please help me to do that? i don't know how i can re-execute the request. please post an answer by editing my code, it will be helpful for me and other person.

Comment: @Danish no... only showing old data... but while i'm clearing cache, then showing new data. but i want to show it immediately while update new data.

Comment: Share your recycle view adapter code.

Comment: @Danish i just updated my question with RecyclerViewAdaptar code. please check.

Comment: how are you updating your data?

Comment: @Danish i was said, while i'm opening that app to my phone or emulator, it's showing the recent data. but in this same time, if i'm updating more data to my server, and close that app and open again, it's not updating the new data. while i'm clearing cache, then it's showing new data. so, now i want to update my real-time data to my app... such as, swipe to refresh and auto update data while new data storage.

Comment: In your onDestroy method clear the list and using lstAnime.clear() this will clear your previous list evrytime you kill your app.So making new request on every relaunch.

Comment: @Danish can you please post an answer? in my case, onDestroy method is not working in my Home.java activity. same problems.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @Danish that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Notify your recycler view using notifyDataSetChanged in your jsonrequest() method.Clear cache using requestQueue.getCache().clear();
Check the below code:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    private final String JSON_URL = "https://mywebsite.org/news/api.php";
    private JsonArrayRequest request ;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
    private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    ProgressBar loading;
    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter;
    **SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;**
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        loading = (ProgressBar)root.findViewById(R.id.bar);
        loading.setMax(100);
        lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);

        jsonrequest();
        setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);
         **swipeRefreshLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh()
                {
                    jsonrequest();
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });**
        return root;
    }

    private void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {

                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                        Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                        anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        anime.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                        anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("category"));
                        anime.setAuthor(jsonObject.getString("admin"));
                        anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail"));
                        lstAnime.add(anime);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(myadapter != null)
                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    //This indicates that the request has either time out or there is no connection
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TimeOut...! No Internet",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    // Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed To Receive Data",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    //Indicates that the server responded with a error response
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Our Server Under Maintenance",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //Indicates that there was network error while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Not Responding",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    // Indicates that the server response could not be parsed
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Reload Again!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.getCache().clear();//add this line
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {

         myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),lstAnime);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

        // grid columns is 2
        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                // 0 is first one and 9 is first one all of others are 2 columns
                if (position == 0 || position == 9) {
                    return 2;
                }
                return 1;}
        });
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);

    }

}
```

Also in your recyclerviewadapter.java add this line to recycler adapter constructor:

```
   public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Request option for Glide
    option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);
}
```

**Remove your nested scrollview from your xml file:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".fragments.Home"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/bar"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recview">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: it's not working. same problem.

Comment: Have u tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: which browser? if i clear app cache, it's showing new data. but user will not do that every time.

Comment: after added this.notifyDataSetChanged(); to my recyclerviewadapter.java, it's also not working.

Comment: Actually whenver you are relaunching your app the data is being loaded from cache which actually holds your old data.

Comment: after updating your data on your server,clear your browser cache.

Comment: it's not a solution... i was told in my post that, while i'm clearing cache from the app, it's showing new data. so what is the helpful think in your answer?

Comment: See my new answer.

Comment: now it's working. thanks. but i have one more question... don't worry, i will accept your answer. can you please tell me how i can do swipe to refresh? i already have the xml file done, but i'm tired with java.. what to do? can you please edit your answer and post in below how to do that?

Comment: Yaa i know how to do it i have code snippet for that on my laptop but now i am replying you from my phone and its 00:10 here so In Shaa Allah ta'aala tommorrow i will update the code.

Comment: Sorry for being late actually its friday today so i have go mosque for friday prayer.Have you nested your recyclerview inside swiperefreshlayout.Share your xml code.I will write answer matching ur xml too.

Comment: i just updated my question with xml file... please check.

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: swipe to refresh not working dear... not updating new data while swipe.

Comment: I have tried the code and its working perfectly fine.I think it may be layout problem

Comment: Give a parent layout to your swipeRefresh layout and see if its working or not.

Comment: if i'm giving parent layout, it's showing nothing.

Comment: Upload your new code.

Comment: Is it showing the swipe indicator??

Comment: yes it's showing the indicator....

Comment: Use framelayout as parent.

Comment: please do that for me in your answer.

Comment: I checked your xml code and didnt find any problem except for nestedscroll view which slowed the app in my case.